# Grails GGTS doesn't provide code folding for groovy files

Tags: grails

GGTS seems to provide code folding for my *.gsp files but not for my *.groovy files. Is there any way to turn on code folding for *.groovy files?

Comment: Go to workbench preferences -> General -> Editors -> Structured Text Editors, and check the "Enable folding" box.

Comment: @ Visme I just checked. I already have it set as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GGTS does seem to provide Groovy code folding as long as you are working on a Grails project using the local project explorer. And even at that it is only folding at the method level. The code folding seems to go away when you start to use any remote project explorer. Another solution might be Sublime text which provides any level of code folding even when editing remotely but is a little work to set up.